# SVN to Git having custom folder structure

Tags: git, git-svn

I have reviewed a number of stackoverflow questions and havent been able to find a solution for my issue.

We are migrating from SVN to GIT. Unfortunately, we do not have the standard folder structure.

Here is the structure I am trying to migrate over

ProductA

- branches
- ToolA
- ToolB
- tags
- trunk

"branches" folder has this structure:

- main_code_base  -- considered as the trunk for our code base
- release_1
- release_2
- rel_3
- rel4
- rele2.x
- feature1
- feature2

In the git repo, we use "master"as the main branch.
So under master this is the required folder structure.

---

Product (folder)

- ProductA (sub folder)
  Tools (folder, same level as Product)
- ToolA
- ToolB

I looked at various suggestions and have tried many different commands.
Started with git svn clone, then moved to use
git svn init and git svn fetch
manually modify the $GIT_DIR/config file and provided different combination of values for fetch and branches under [svn-remote "svn"]

None of it works.

As a last resort, I am prepared to modify the svn structure and move ProductA/ToolA and ProductA/ToolB to ProductA/branches/ToolA and ProductA/branches/ToolB if it will make it easier to migrate.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `git svn` can be taught about the (custom) location of branches/tags using `--trunk=`, `--tags=` and `--branches=` (multiple times each if necessary). Did you use them already?

Comment: eftshift0, Thanks for your reply. Yes I did use the options for trunk, tags and branches. I tried with svn2git and looked into a number SF questions. Our folder structure is not standard. Talked to couple of people in my company, they suggested moving tools to a separate repo. This would make it easier to migrate over as the folder structure would be more in alignment.  
I will update the questions after I try moving Tools to a separate repo.